Classification of Fighter Types / Approaches
In a comparative context (such as when talking about combats between very different practitioners, between followers of different style and the like), does a relatively broadly-applicable set of terminology exist for describing different 'types' ('archetypes'?) of practitioners based on what their (hopeful) approach to achieving victory is? E.g. stereotypically aikidoka are reputed to be evasive counterattack-throwers, boxers are big on footwork and jabs, and Shotokan karateka on strong direct but rigid strikes (I understand that the stereotypes may be exaggerated or wrong).
But are there commonly recognised and widely understood terms for these kinds of archetypes (even if multiple archetypes can be found within the same style or family of styles), and if yes, is there a list of the most widely recurring and distinct ones? (Of course, I'm assuming that the classification is likely to be messy, with practitioners typically combining multiple types, but still there being a sense of a given subset of the types being dominant in a given person.)

I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Do you mean things like striking vs. grappling, internal vs. external, hard vs. soft, and so on? Would that be a helpful answer? Or are you looking for something else?

Yeah, those three axes seem to be useful as an example of classification, though I suspect there's more than three axes (also internal vs. external and whether it's in lockstep with soft vs. hard is confusing). Are there? Alternatively, things like 'this is a fragile speedster, this is a stonewall, this is a heavy grappler' but for real life (since those examples are for fictional archetypes, and likely don't reflect the distinctions that are important IRL but invisible on-screen).

Okay, I think I can comment on that. I'll write something up.

Martial arts practices are categorized a number of different ways. Most martial arts are a combination of these. And rarely do you find a martial art that is entirely one way or the other. For example, karate has grappling in it to a lesser degree, even though it's considered a striking art. It's not a purely, 100% striking based art, in other words. In fact, some would say karate is at least half grappling, the way it was originally designed.
First, there's traditional vs. modern.  Traditional martial arts have many theories and practices which are to be done just because that's the way they've always been done. It relies on what has been taught traditionally in the past. Traditional martial arts can actually be modern, too, in the sense that they were invented in recent history. It's just that they continue the traditions of other styles on which they base their new style. A subset of traditional martial arts is known as classical martial arts, which trace their origin to the years prior to the "Do" art invention in Japan, circa 1900. The purpose of classical martial arts was always to prepare the student for combat, either on the battlefield or one-on-one. It was considered a collection of practical knowledge about how to fight. Whereas, many of the more modern traditional martial arts focus on personal growth over preparing people to fight. This was effectively the issue behind the change from "-jitsu" (art) martial arts to "-do" (way) martial arts in Japan. For example, Jujitsu vs. Judo. Some of the more modern traditional martial arts still have the focus entirely or mostly on combat readiness rather than personal growth, but it's more rare. Some examples of traditional martial arts include: Karate, Kung-Fu, Silat, Capoeira, and Judo. As for "modern" (non-traditional) martial arts, the emphasis is on critical analysis to select theories and practices that lead to a better result. They're breaking away from tradition, because they would argue that tradition is not a good reason to believe things work the best or even work at all. One famous example of this was Jeet Kune Do, Bruce Lee's style. Bruce Lee began with traditional martial arts and then relentlessly removed things that weren't useful and added things which were. Mixed Martial Arts are another example. Contemporary Wushu and Brazilian Jiujitsu are other examples, although both still retain some elements of their traditional origin. Many modern martial arts are based on one or more traditional martial arts, taking whatever they find useful and merging it with new theories and practices.
There's hard and soft. A hard martial art involves using force against force. A soft martial art yields to force, instead. So for example, karate tends to be categorized as a hard style while jujitsu is categorized as a soft style. Soft styles use sensitivity to feel or perceive when force is being applied and will attempt to adjust their defense as it's happening, usually after physically connecting with their opponents in some manner. Whereas, hard styles rely on strength, speed, and power to assert their will on their opponent. Most martial arts are a combination of both hard and soft but rely more heavily on one than the other.
Another way to categorize martial arts is grappling vs. striking. A grappling art would first grab onto their opponent somewhere and then either throw them or unbalance them and force them to the ground. On the ground, grappling arts would then attempt to submit them or hold them there. Wrestling, Judo, and Jiujitsu are grappling arts. Whereas a striking art would try to keep themselves free from being held so that they can throw punches, kicks, elbows, knees, and headbutts at their opponent to inflict immediate damage such as broken bones, knock-outs, and organ damage. The ideal for a striking based art is to end the fight quickly with one strike, whereas grappling based arts might have to struggle with an opponent in order to maintain control of them. But as is often the case, striking doesn't always work quickly, and the fighters end up grappling anyway. So a good fighter will need to know how to do both. Striking based arts include styles such as Karate, Kung-fu, Taekwondo, Boxing, Savate, Capoeira, and so on. Once again, most styles are not purely one or the other. Many are a mix of both, but they'll tend to emphasize one more than the other.
There's also internal vs. external. Internal martial arts are those which do something inside of a practitioner's body that's hard or impossible to see. Whereas external martial arts involve simple biomechanics that are easily observed by others. Internal does not necessarily refer to "chi" or "ki", but it can. Instead, it usually refers to internal mechanics in styles such as Tai-chi, Hsing-Yi, and Bagua. Internal mechanics is a way of moving that involves using the alignment of bones and the tension created by muscles and tendons to make use of the structure of the body to exert forces which have various qualities. Because that's done inside of the body, it's hard or impossible to see. Whereas an external martial art involves simple body mechanics that we all know how to do. You flex your muscles to accelerate your fist at an opponent while bracing with your legs and keeping your torso tight in order to support your punch and absorb its impact. External martial arts include Boxing, Karate, Taekwondo, Muay Thai, and so on. The most advanced skills taught in some external martial arts involve basic applications of internal mechanics. And internal martial arts have to move in external ways sometimes as well.
Another categorization is weapons based vs. empty hand. In a weapons based martial art, you learn how to use weapons such as the knife, sword, sticks, staff, and chain. Weapons are also called "force multipliers", for their ability to give the wielder a big advantage. Many weapons based martial arts will base their empty handed style on the same movements they would use if they had a weapon, which improves muscle memory and decreases the amount of time training. Some examples of weapons based martial arts include escrima / Kali, Silat, and Bujinkan Ninjutsu. Whereas, empty handed martial arts concentrate entirely on what to do without weapons. Some examples of empty handed martial arts include Karate, Taekwondo, Boxing, and Judo. While empty handed martial arts may not train in weapons as much, they often do introduce weapons to supplement their regular training. It's usually an afterthought, and it wouldn't necessarily change anything about their empty handed style.
Another distinction sometimes seen in martial arts is battlefield / village combat vs. personal defense. Some martial arts were invented for the battlefield in war or for defending a village, typically in ancient feudal times in Japan or China. That will affect the style in many, often subtle ways. For example, many of these styles assume you're wearing armor of some kind, along with weapons such as swords. The kicks and punches may look different from other styles, because with armor on, you can't easily snap punches and kicks. And the emphasis might be on moving in ways that are optimal for sword fighting. Examples include many Samurai based classical Japanese Jujitsu styles and Bujinkan Ninjutsu. I recall hearing that certain Chinese kung-fu styles were considered village defense styles as well, but I forget their names off the top of my head. Those kung-fu styles will use spears, broadswords, and shields as their main weapons, and tactics will involve coordinating attack and defense with others on your side. Because battlefields are usually flat and expansive, it's assumed you have a good amount of space to perform all your techniques. That affects the kinds of techniques that are taught. It's often taught as personal self-defense, however, and not explained that it was actually based on this village protection concept. Most martial arts you encounter will be personal self-defense based arts, instead. They often have closer range fighting tactics and more narrow stances, because a lack of space to move around is assumed. Those include styles like Karate, Wing Chun, Boxing, and so on.
There are also sports based vs. non-sports based martial arts. Sports based martial arts will teach a limited set of techniques and strategies with a system of rules for safety and for scoring purposes. The main goal of sports based martial arts is to allow for a safe way to train and compete with each other in order to make continuous progress without serious injury. The idea is to allow for a way of fully resisting each other, but without getting hurt. Only with liveness and resistance are you able to pressure test a martial art. Some sport based martial arts include Judo, Taekwondo, Boxing, Muay Thai, Wrestling, and Brazilian Jiujitsu. Other martial arts avoid competition altogether, for a number of reasons. One of the most common reasons is to avoid creating habits that could end up hurting you in a real life situation. Another reason often given is that training for sports means they can't use their complete art which might include things banned under sports rules, such as strikes to the eyes, neck, groin, and joints or grappling on fingers and wrists. The goal of most non-sports based martial arts is to seriously hurt their opponent as quickly as possible, which is exactly what sports based martial arts don't want to happen. Some examples of non-sports based martial arts include Bujinkan Ninjutsu, Karate, Wing Chun, Silat, and Krav Maga. Although these styles don't often train for competition, there are some cases where they might incorporate it just for those who do want to compete, or individual practitioners of these styles may attempt to compete on their own. It doesn't change the way their style is taught, however.
There's also the category of short range vs. long range which is also referred to as infighting vs. outfighting. This category only applies to striking based arts. Short range tactics are those which are done very close to your opponent, such as elbows, knees, headbutts, upper cuts, hooking under the arms or holding onto the back of the neck as you strike, grabbing and pulling hair, biting, etc. In the short range, a lot of things done in the long range won't work, because there's no time to react. For example, you can't block punches and kicks while in the short range. That's why a lot of people prefer to keep their distance rather than stay in close to an opponent. It's out of fear and a lack of training. You can't usually throw punches that are at full force, either, because you can't get a sufficient amount of space. You can't do kicks to the head. But the short range also allows you to begin grappling, with the clinch. And when that begins, you can take control of your opponent while avoiding heavy strikes due to the fact that your opponent won't have the distance to throw them. Once you make connection with your opponent, you'll be able to use sensitivity to feel for what he's about to do, which gives you the time needed to react better. Whereas, long range fighting involves a lot of footwork and movement. You're free to move. Nobody is holding you, and you're in no danger of being held. You'll have more time to react to incoming strikes. You can see your opponent better and can analyze his patterns and habits in order to devise a strategy against him. Strikes in this range can be very powerful, because with distance comes more time to accelerate a kick or a punch. They can result in broken bones and knock-outs. Short range fighters can also break bones and cause knock-outs, but it often requires greater strength and speed, and special adaptations of the strikes to that close-in range. Wing Chun kung-fu is an example of a purely short range fighting art. Taekwondo is an example of a purely long range fighting style. You'll also hear about the mid-range, and as you might suspect it's just in between short and long distance. In truth, most striking based arts are a combination of all ranges, but they often concentrate on one range more than the other. In Boxing, the range choice just depends on the coach and the fighter's preferences.
I'm sure that isn't the entire list. For example, there are western vs. eastern styles. There are male vs. female styles. There are tall vs. short styles. There are animal vs. non-animal styles. And probably many more that others might think of.
Hope that helps.


does a relatively broadly-applicable set of terminology exist for describing different 'types'[?]

No, these are basically context-dependent.
By archetypes, I assume you mean something like the classification of boxers.

Every boxer falls into one of the four boxing styles: In-Fighter, Out-Boxer, Slugger and Boxer-Puncher.

These apply only to boxing, where only punching is allowed. These are meaningless in the context of judo, for example, where grappling is allowed but punching is not. Judo has its own (non-standard) categories used to describe fighters based for example on: gripping styles, favorite techniques, use of groundwork, or reliance on penalties.
When there is a shared context like MMA, types are generally around a fighter's predominant martial arts style: Muay Thai, kickboxing, BJJ, judo, etc. The more granular types within those styles are ignored.

Thank you for the example of archetypes in boxing, that will probably help me narrow down the question (by acting as an existing real-world example) if I end up pursuing it further in a more specific context.
